# Having different automapping "configurations"

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping, automapping

I want to have two different mapping configurations. I need to somehow pass arguments to conventions so they can behave differently. Beside using `lock` and static fields how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution: `Conventions.Find` allows to find convention instances.

```
var map = AutoMap.AssemblyOf<AutomappingConfiguration>(new AutomappingConfiguration())
    .Conventions.AddFromAssemblyOf<AutomappingConfiguration>()
    .UseOverridesFromAssemblyOf<AutomappingConfiguration>();

foreach (var c in map.Conventions.Find<TableConvention>())
{
    c.AllWritable = allWritable;
}
```